# How can I remove unwanted object from a video and see what's behind it?

Tags: video, editing, adobe, filter

If for example I have a video and there is a person that moves but is always partially blocked by an object, can I remove it somehow to get a clear video footage? I tried Adobe content aware Filter, it did not help.

Comment: Hi - please could you add a screen shot to help explain what you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this. You obviously can't just "reveal" footage that is obstructed, you'll have to recreate it. It's hard to judge the shot since you provided no screenshot, but the easiest method would probably be to grab a frame and use photoshop to remove the object and reconstruct the person by re-using parts of the existing image. If you have to reconstruct a face, I would say that it's an impossible task. A shoulder however should be possible. This way. You only have to create a "patch" for every other, or every frame, depending on the movement, then overlay those patches to your footage and track the footage if needed, to attach the patch with the tracked movement to your footage.